# How to set time duration for html video

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

am trying to assign time duration to the playlist.... but as am using onend that function is calling after completing that video, but what i want is the video should play only on its assigned time duration after that it should stops and next video should play..am using following code...

```
<video id="myVideo" height="100%" width="100%" autoplay onended="run();">   
        <source id="ss" src="video/video1.ogg" type='video/ogg'>
    </video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   // num_files++;
      //alert(num_files);
        video_count =1;
        videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");        
        video=document.getElementById("myVideo");
        time2= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
        function run(){
        for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
        {
            //alert(duration[i]);
             time1= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);

          // alert('ctime'+time1);
             dur_time=parseInt(time2,10)+parseInt(duration[i],10);
          //  alert('dtime'+dur_time);
               video_count++;
                 if(time1<dur_time) 
                 {
                        video_count--;

                //alert(video_count);
               if (video_count > num_files) video_count = 1;

               videoPlayer.setAttribute("src","video/video"+video_count+".ogg");       
            //alert(video_count);
            video.pause();
            video.load();
            video.play();
            time1= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
                 }
       }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tap into the `timeupdate` event which is updated when playing the video:

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {

   if (this.currentTime >= dur_time) {
       this.pause();
       /// next action
   }

}, false);
```

You could probably achieve the same using polling (ie. `setTimeout`/`setInterval`/`requestAnimationFrame`) but using the event is a more clean approach and will only update on an actual time change.

**Update**

You can also stop a video after a certain duration this way, however, this is not "frame accurate" but can perhaps help in some extreme cases:

```
var seconds = 3;

setTimeout(stopVideo, seconds * 1000);  /// ms
video.play();

function stopVideo() {
    if (video.isPlaying) {
        video.pause();
        /// next action
    }
}
```

Comment: timeupdate will work fine but problem is if the video is small and time duration is more the video has to get repeat.. but in this case its not happening.. i added loop to the video tag but the same video will repeat after time out also...so how can this be avoided?

Comment: @user3145475 if the video is repeating the currentTime will just reset for each time it loops. What you can do in this case is to use a `setTimeout(stopVideo, wantedDuration)` which you set at the same time as you start the video. This time the function `stopVideo` can call the pause method. If the videos are shorter than even allowing this then I think you are out of luck as we can only do so much with what the browser permits and setTimeout is not that accurate. I'll update my answer with a short example.

Comment: instead of setTimeout we can use the following code and its working fine for me video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
           // alert(video_count);
             dur_time=parseInt(time2,10)+7;
          
        if (this.currentTime >= 7 || time1 >= dur_time) {
       this.pause();
       advanceVideo();  
       time2= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);   
   }
     time1= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
        }, false);

Comment: i have one more doubt in this, as we are storing all the videos in one folder,if any of the video is deleted... the play list will stop and its not skipping to next one.. is their any way to check availability of the file and if not we can skip to next one

Answer (score 0):

instead of setTimeout we can use the following code and its working fine for me

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
           // alert(video_count);
             dur_time=parseInt(time2,10)+7;

        if (this.currentTime >= 7 || time1 >= dur_time) {
       this.pause();
       advanceVideo();  
       time2= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);   
   }
     time1= Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
        }, false);
```